# Value conversions for a declarative ui/view layer?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, data-binding, view, declarative

I've got an app (desktop, not web or .net) with a simple MVC architecture whereby values, and lists of values, can be displayed from the model by a simple binding mechanism.

The model is a tree structure scalar and array nodes.  Some nodes are raw values, some objects that have members sub-nodes.

The view-level binding syntax is similar to:

```
app_root.some_node.prices[1]  // single "price" object 
app_root.some_node.prices     // all "price" objects
```

Now, I have the need to present these values after running them though some sort of conversion process.

For the sake of example: Live currency conversion.  i.e. Something that's more complex than just formatting and may fail or be dependent on application state to some degree.

How might I add this capability while still keeping the MVC system and binding syntax sane?

The two immediate options I can think of are:

```
// Fake "arguments" to a generic app-level converter node?
//
// Very hack-ish looking and now the app has a new 
// global "currency_converter" node.
//
app_root.currency_converter.euro.app_root.some_node.prices[1]
app_root.currency_converter.yen.app_root.some_node.prices[1]

// Ad-hoc extension to the "price" objects?
//
// Cleaner binding path, but now I need modify the "price" object for
// each new currency.  This also seems wrong.
//
app_root.some_node.prices[1].asEuro
app_root.some_node.prices[1].asYen // etc.

// Adding a post-fix converter option? 
//
// Still a cleaner binding path, but now there must exist some magic 
// conversion system/registry that the "As" sub-node must know how to talk to.
// 
app_root.some_node.prices[1].As.Euro
app_root.some_node.prices[1].As.Yen // etc.
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the second option because the first one will result in convertor bloat, you would end up with a lot of converters which you have to manage.

I don't know on which platform or technology you are working but sometimes it is helpful to see how others have done it, i work with WPF which is Microsoft's desktop application stack and they have a binding object which can use formatting like this:

```
<Label Content={Binding Path=CurrentAmount, Format=Cost: {0:C}} />
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`Binding` is an object here and `Format` is one of its parameters besides `Path`, so perhaps  you could implement something similar in your framework.

**Edit:** I showed you how WPF performed simple formatting but the system also has the capability for more complex conversions, and it can be applied in the same way formatting can be.

Here is the same sample from before but with conversion added this time:

```
<Label Content={Binding Path=CurrentAmount, Format=Cost: {0:C}, Converter=myConverter />
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As you can see you can use a converter parameter as well, myConverter is actually a class that implements a WPF interface called `IValueConverter` that can convert values back and forth from the view layer to the model and vice versa.

Comment: Edited question to clarify that the conversion is more complex than just formatting.  In any case, thanks for sharing the WPF way.  Very interesting.

Comment: So, in WPF "Converter" is a sort of named argument to "Binding"?  Cool. What namespace is "myConverter" in?  Same as "Binding"?  But in any case, Binding has to know enough to call functions on  the supplied IValueConverter, correct?  (Also, as you can see the syntax I have to work with does not allow for "arguments".  Though you can sort of fake it as I did in the first example.)

Comment: @nonot1 It is actually a property of the Binding object as well as Format is. I actually didn't show you the whole thing, you can't use my converter like this but i wanted you to get an idea how it is done in WPF, nevertheless myConverter is a instance of a class implementing the `IValueConverter` interface and yes the Binding object has to know about it in order to call the conversion methods. That's all i can help you with.